# Sending hex packets in python

Tags: python, hex, packet

How would I send hex data in a packet? I'm trying to copy a packet exactly by using the hex instead of ASCII. All I'm looking for is what the sendto argument would be if, say, the hex I needed to send was 00AD12.

Comment: Packet type shouldn't effect what I'm trying to do, but UDP.

Comment: Actually, it does, since UDP is a connectionless protocol where you'll usually use `sendto` instead of `send` or a file-like object. However, note that the tasks of converting a hexdecimal string to bytes and the one of sending any bytes are distinct and independent.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) to convert between bytes (typically expressed in hexadecimal fashion) and numbers:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('!I', 0xAD12)
b'\x00\x00\xad\x12'
```

If you have a hex *string* and want to convert it to bytes, use [`binascii.unhexlify`](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.unhexlify('ad12')
b'\xad\x12'
```

Comment: So I would assign a variable to that then use the variable as the data to be sent?

Comment: @Michael You can do that, but you don't have to. You can either write `tmp = struct.pack(...)` `sock.send(tmp)`, or `sock.send(struct.pack(...))`, where sock is a connected socket.

Comment: The string I need to convert is tossing out of range errors, is there a fix or should I just put it in a string and put \x before every byte?

Comment: @Michael If you have a hex *string* that is a representation of bytes, use `binascii.unhexlify`. Updated the answer with that. Putting it in a string (a byte string starting with a `b` in Python 3) and prefixing every two hex digits with `\x` has the same result.